# Display SVG for New Content in Django

Tags: python, django, svg, django-templates, django-views

I want to display an SVG for any new content created in the past 2 days. I'm just wondering how I'd do this.

views.py:

```
def short_story_list(request):
shorts = models.Short.objects.filter(is_live=True).order_by('-created_at')
return render(request, 'stories/short_story_list.html', {'shorts': shorts})
```

short_story_list.html:

```
{% for short in shorts %}
        <div class="block">
            <h3><a href="{% url 'short-detail' short.slug %}">{{ short.title }}</a></h3>
            {% if short.created_at %}
                <img src="{% static 'svg/outline-fiber_new-24px.svg' %}">
            {% endif %}
            <br>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

How do I make sure that only the SVG is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
date_2_back = today - datetime.timedelta(days=2)

shorts_latest = models.Short.objects.filter(start_time__lt=today, end_time__gt=date_2_back)
```

You can use `timedelta()` if you just want the `shorts` for last 2 days.

Alternatively, you can add a function in model that returns `true` if the `created_at` lies between the two dates:

```
def latest_condition(self):
    if self.created_at - datetime.date.today() <= datetime.timedelta(days=2):
          return True
    else:
          return False
```